# How browserify makes Node.js modules to work in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

Ii really can't understand some work behind `browserify`. When using pure JavaScript modules it seems "easy" to convert it to browser code, even if with many dependencies.

But `browserify` does more:

> Many npm modules that don't do IO will just work after being
>   browserified. Others take more work.
>
> Many node built-in modules have been wrapped to work in the browser,
>   but only when you explicitly `require()` or use their functionality.
>
> When you require() any of these modules, you will get a
>   browser-specific shim.

And again:

> - process.nextTick(), __dirname, and __filename node-isms work
> - get browser versions of the node core libraries events, stream, path, url,
>     assert, buffer, util, querystring, http, vm, and crypto when you
>     require() them

So... `process.nextTick()`, `__dirname` inside the browser... even `http`? This doesn't make sense to me... how `__dirname` is supposed to work inside a browser?

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914810/node-browserify-for-node-core-libraries/18543245#18543245). I provided an [answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914810/node-browserify-for-node-core-libraries/18543245#18543245) which should be helpful here as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`process.nextTick()` simply runs a callback later.
In a browser, this is simulated using `setTimeout(func, 0)`, `setImmediate`, or `requestAnimationFrame()`.

`__dirnamne` and `__filename` are simply variables that browserify injects at compile-time based on the original path to the file.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Still have many questions about lot of other modules, like `http` or `stream`. I guess I have to start looking at source code, but it scares me :)

Comment: @Gremo: `http` is a wrapper around AJAX; `stream` is a wrapper around arrays.  Read https://github.com/shtylman/node-browser-resolve/tree/v0.1.1/builtin  (these files were later moved into separate npm packages;  https://github.com/search?q=browserify&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults)