# node browserify for node core libraries

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

This is a question just to confirm my understanding of node browserify.

[substack/node-browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) says:

> compatibility: Many npm modules that don't do IO will just work after
>   being browserified. Others take more work. Many node built-in modules
>   have been wrapped to work in the browser, but only when you explicitly
>   require() or use their functionality.

--

> get browser versions of the node core libraries events, stream, path,
>   url, assert, buffer, util, querystring, http, vm, and crypto when you
>   require() them

Does node browserify takes the source-code of the node build-in modules, and construct a bundled file; by selecting the current working NVM version properly?

Actually, I used browserify first time with [maxogden/websocket-stream](https://github.com/maxogden/websocket-stream), and works amazingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not use node core modules in their initial form. Certain functions don't make sense in the browser at all or at least have to be adapted to make sense.

Instead browserify uses a module called [browser-builtins](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins) in order to provide meaningful alternatives.

Inspecting the [package.json file](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins/blob/e3d1e73453297d78d0d480e089d6488c9d094105/package.json#L21-L28) of this module you can see which core modules are provided by external packages.

The remaining ones come [from here](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins/tree/master/builtin).

As you can see, some modules like [fs](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins/blob/master/builtin/fs.js) don't make sense in the browser (at least not at this point).

[Others](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins/blob/master/builtin/assert.js) however can [easily be adapted](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/node-browser-builtins/commits/master/builtin/assert.js) to work in the browser.

### Edit:

The above is not entirely true anymore. In the spirit of modularity the latest browserify no longer depends on browser-builtins, but instead each module shim is published separately.

For more information please review [builtins.js](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/e35437af10b9b628885102a6b8e0d1f39cb16c8d/lib/builtins.js) and [package.json](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/blob/e35437af10b9b628885102a6b8e0d1f39cb16c8d/package.json#L39-L57)

Comment: Thanks Thorsten Lorenz , since it says *Many node built-in modules have been wrapped to work in the browser* ,I somehow thought it depends on the node core directly, but I understand in fact, it depends on some hard manual work by alexgorbatchev, amazing.